# Question about the Dirac adjoint and Feynman slash notation

Tags: dirac-equation, complex-numbers, dirac-matrices

I was trying to prove the identity $\overline{\displaystyle{\not}{a}\displaystyle{\not}{b}\dots \displaystyle{\not}{p}} = \displaystyle{\not}{p}\dots \displaystyle{\not}{b}\displaystyle{\not}{a}$. On simplifying the LHS I end up with $ \overline{ \displaystyle{\not}{p}^{}} \dots \overline{ \displaystyle{\not}{b}^{}} \ \overline{ \displaystyle{\not}{a}^{}} $.

I'm wondering if $ \overline{ \displaystyle{\not} p} = \gamma^0  \displaystyle{\not} p^{\dagger}  \gamma^0 = \displaystyle{\not} p$ as this would let me complete the final step.

Comment: Does the overbar mean complex conjugate? For the mostly plus metric we do have $\gamma_a^\dagger = \gamma_0 \gamma_a \gamma_0$.

Comment: Hi! The overbar is defined as $\overline{\gamma} = \gamma^0 \gamma^{\dagger} \gamma^0$

Answer (score 1):

Usually, gamma-matrices are chosen in such a way that they satisfy the hermiticity condition $\gamma^{\mu\dagger}=\gamma^0\gamma^\mu\gamma^0$, and that is what you need, but this choice is not mandatory.

Comment: Ah, thanks! Do the elements of the 4 vector $p_{\mu}$ also satisfy $\gamma^0 p_{\mu}^{\dagger} \gamma^0 = p_{\mu}$

Comment: @Aquarkyname : Yes, as $p^\dagger_\mu=p_\mu$ and typically $(\gamma^0)^2=1$.

Comment: Why does $p_{\mu}^{\dagger} = p_{\mu}$. Does the Hermitian adjoint not act on the elements of the complex 4 vector?

Comment: @Aquarkyname : https://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node144.html

Comment: Ah, I should have used a different letter. $p$ is just an arbitrary 4-vector, not the momentum operator. To show the identity above, I would also need to show $a_{\mu}^{\dagger} = a_{\mu}$ for instance

Comment: @Aquarkyname : if $p_\mu$ is arbitrary (complex), your initial equality does not seem to hold.

Comment: @akhmeteli here $p$ is not the first-quantized momentum operator from QM, but simply a label, so your comment about why in QM the momentum operator is Hermitian doesn't apply. However, the components of the 4-vector $p$ are real numbers so obviously $p_{\mu}^{\dagger} = p_{\mu}$. OP's identity indeed doesn't hold when $p_{\mu} \in \mathbb{C}$, which is very easy to check.

Comment: @Prof.Legolasov : so we interpreted the OP's question in the comment differently.